# Why does this tensorflow loop require so much memory?

Tags: memory-management, tensorflow

I have a contrived version of a complicated network:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.ones([1000])
b = tf.ones([1000])

for i in range(int(1e6)):
    a = a * b
```

My intuition is that this should require very little memory. Just the space for the initial array allocation and a string of commands that utilizes the nodes and overwrites the memory stored in tensor 'a' at each step. But memory usage grows quite rapidly.

What is going on here, and how can I decrease memory usage when I compute a tensor and overwrite it a bunch of times?

Edit:

Thanks to Yaroslav's suggestions the solution turned out to be using a while_loop to minimize the number of nodes on the graph. This works great and is much faster, requires far less memory, and is all contained in-graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.ones([1000])
b = tf.ones([1000])

cond = lambda _i, _1, _2: tf.less(_i, int(1e6))
body = lambda _i, _a, _b: [tf.add(_i, 1), _a * _b, _b]

i = tf.constant(0)
output = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, a, b])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(output)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `a*b` command translates to `tf.mul(a, b)`, which is equivalent to `tf.mul(a, b, g=tf.get_default_graph())`. This command adds a `Mul` node to the current `Graph` object, so you are trying to add 1 million `Mul` nodes to the current graph. That's also problematic since you can't serialize Graph object larger than 2GB, there are some checks that may fail once you are dealing with such a large graph.

I'd recommend reading [Programming Models for Deep Learning](http://mxnet-tqchen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/program_model.html) by MXNet folks. TensorFlow is "symbolic" programming in their terminology, and you are treating it as imperative.

To get what you want using Python loop you could construct multiplication op once, and run it repeatedly, using `feed_dict` to feed updates

```
mul_op = a*b
result = sess.run(a)
for i in range(int(1e6)):
  result = sess.run(mul_op, feed_dict={a: result})
```

For more efficiency you could use `tf.Variable` objects and `var.assign` to avoid Python<->TensorFlow data transfers

Comment: That makes sense. I'd only like to call sess.run once though, and handle all computation from input to output in one step, since I'm backproping over a large graph. Is it possible to do this loop in-graph without adding extra nodes?

Comment: If you save inputs to a*b in `tf.Variable` objects, you would isolate it's dependencies, so you could do `sess.run` on that node a million times without having to evaluate anything else in the graph

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding. Let's say 'b' is a trainable weight matrix that gets updated during back-prop. If I call sess.run more than once, not only do I incur additional overhead for multiple sess.run calls, I disconnect that computation from the gradient computation and will need to do some messy work to make sure it gets updated properly. Are these assumptions correct? I guess I wish there was a better way to handle this in-graph.

Comment: Overhead for session.run call is about 80 usec so a million calls would have 80 seconds of overhead. There's also TensorFlow [while loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#while_loop) if you want to keep it down to single .run call